# Is there a way to use more than one DNS simultaneously in Linux?

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, unix

When I'm connecting to the VPN at work, I frequently run into problems with sites blocked by OpenDNS, and also being limited to the DNS entries on their DNS server.

I'm wondering if there is a way to have domain-name resolution go to one server, and if that name lookup fails, to have it try another. Solving this problem would basically let you to **use the union of DNS entries from multiple servers**.

**Caveat:** It seems like a prioritized list of DNS servers in `/etc/resolv.conf` will not fall through to subsequent entries if the name lookup fails, it will only if the primary DNS server is actually down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't really use a union as far as I'm aware (although a custom resolver to do that wouldn't be impossible), but what you *can* do easily enough is run a local resolver that forwards requests for a certain set of domains to the authoritative nameservers.  I use `dnscache` for this, myself, and it's near-trivial, but BIND can be easily configured to do that same thing.

This doesn't work so well if you've got a large number of domains that are being blocked, but for the usual VPN case (of a few domains that are "internal only") this method works really well.

Comment: Yeah this would work pretty well for me. I've only got the internal company domain name to look up.

Comment: Post another question if you need specific config snippets for either BIND or dnscache; I've got them both to hand.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't split tunneling effectively take care of this?